# About rational number in java programming, to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2

Tags: java, biginteger, rational-number

The purpose of this code is to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2. But my loop can't be executed correctly. 
 The result of r1 is 3/4 instead of 99/100, what's wrong with my code?
 I think my loop can be run because the y I can get it correctly. 
 So how can i correct my code and make it able to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2 ? Thank you for answering.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Rational {
// Data fields for numerator and denominator
private BigInteger numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
private BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.ONE;


/** Construct a rational with default properties */
public Rational() {
this(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE);
}

/** Construct a rational with specified numerator and denominator */
public Rational(BigInteger numerator, BigInteger denominator) {
   BigInteger gcd=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(gcd(numerator, 
   denominator)));
   BigInteger r1=new 
   BigInteger(String.valueOf(denominator.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)));
     this.numerator = (r1.multiply(numerator)).divide(gcd);
     this.denominator = (denominator.abs()).divide(gcd);
    }

 /** Find GCD of two numbers */
 private static long gcd(BigInteger n, BigInteger d) {
 BigInteger n1 = n.abs();
 BigInteger n2 = d.abs();
 int gcd = 1;

 for (int k = 1; (new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k))).compareTo(n1)<=0 && 
 (new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k))).compareTo(n2)<=0; k++) {
 if (n1.mod(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k))).equals(BigInteger.ZERO) && 
 n2.mod(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k))).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) 
 gcd = k;
 }

 return gcd;
 }

 /** Return numerator */
 public BigInteger getNumerator() {
  return numerator;
 }

 /** Return denominator */
 public BigInteger getDenominator() {
  return denominator;
 }

 /** Add a rational number to this rational */
 public Rational add(Rational secondRational) {
  BigInteger n = 
numerator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator())
.add(denominator.multiply(sec
ondRational.getNumerator()));
  BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
  return new Rational(n, d);
 }

 /** Subtract a rational number from this rational */
 public Rational subtract(Rational secondRational) {
     BigInteger n = 
 (numerator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator()))
.subtract(denominator.multiply(secondRational.getNumerator()));
     BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
  return new Rational(n, d);
 }

 /** Multiply a rational number to this rational */
 public Rational multiply(Rational secondRational) {
     BigInteger n = numerator.multiply(secondRational.getNumerator());
     BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
  return new Rational(n, d);
 }

 /** Divide a rational number from this rational */
 public Rational divide(Rational secondRational) {
     BigInteger n = numerator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
     BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.numerator);
  return new Rational(n, d);
 }

/** Compute the square of this rational number*/
 public Rational square() {
     BigInteger n = numerator.multiply(numerator);
     BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(denominator);
  return new Rational(n, d);
 }

/** toString */
 public String toString() {
      return numerator + "/" + denominator;
 }
}
```

and this is the testRational class
    import java.math.BigInteger;

```
public class TestRational {
   public static void main(String[]args){
    int y = 1;

    BigInteger i=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(1));
    BigInteger a=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(2));
    BigInteger b=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(3));
    BigInteger c=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(5));



    Rational sum = new  Rational(BigInteger.ZERO,a);
    Rational r0 = new Rational(b,b.add(i));
    Rational r2 = new  Rational(a,c);
    Rational r3 = new  Rational(a,c);


    Rational s1 = r3.multiply(r2);
    Rational s2 = r3.square();
    Rational s3 = r2.divide(r3);

    Rational r1 = new  Rational(i,a);
    do{

        sum = sum.add(r0);
        b = b.add(a);
        y++;




    }while(y<49);
        System.out.println(sum.multiply(sum));
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(s3);
        System.out.println(r0);
}
}
```

The purpose of this code is to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2. But my loop can't be executed correctly. 
 The result of r1 is 3/4 instead of 99/100, what's wrong with my code?
 I think my loop can be run because the y I can get it correctly. 
 So how can i correct my code and make it able to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2 ? Thank you for answering.
The purpose of this code is to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2. But my loop can't be executed correctly. 
 The result of r1 is 3/4 instead of 99/100, what's wrong with my code?
 I think my loop can be run because the y I can get it correctly. 
 So how can i correct my code and make it able to calculate (1/2+3/4+...+99/100)^2 ? Thank you for answering.

Comment: The only things changed by the loop are `sum`, `b` and `y` (and this is obvious because it's literally what that loop says to do). There is no reason why `r1`, `s1`, `s2` or `r0` would be affected.

Comment: So how can I make them into the loop without making mistake? I have tried to make r0 inside the loop. But the whole program is failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write it less confusingly, without all the unnecessary stuff and confusing loop. The definition of the sum is (1/2 + 3/4 ... 99/100) so let's start by creating all the fractions in the sum:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i += 2) {
    BigRational t = new BigRational(BigInteger.valueOf(i), BigInteger.valueOf(i + 1));
}
```

They have to be summed, so there has to be a variable declared outside the loop to sum up all those fractions into:

```
Rational sum = new Rational();
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i += 2) {
    Rational t = new Rational(BigInteger.valueOf(i), BigInteger.valueOf(i + 1));
    sum = sum.add(t);
}
```

Then square that and you have your answer. I get:

```
87593039510089573189394173247956745677798336081
-----------------------------------------------
   38416307357189261992010230523038591203840000
```

Which I can't verify but it looks reasonable enough. The expected answer is "a bit less than 50<sup>2</sup>" (because it's the square of 50 terms that are nearly 1, if 0.5 can be called that) and this is close enough.

By the way, stop using `String.valueOf` everywhere in `Rational`. Just work with numbers. And `BigInteger` already implements `gcd`, you don't have to write your own (less efficient) version. I had to replace this otherwise it took too long.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if I don't add String.valueOf, the eclipse will tell me something like 'The constructor BigInteger(long) is not visible'. How can I deal with that? Thank you!

Comment: @Ben.W if you really need to construct a BigInteger from a long, there is `BigInteger.valueOf`, but *you don't* (at least not there). `numerator.gcd(denominator)` is already a `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks, I had corrected my codes. And in fact it was my assignment, I have to change the originally int Rational class to BigInteger Rational class. So I just changed it :). And I corrected my Rational class, so the gcd will not be used. Interestingly, if I don't change my code to `BigInteger gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator)`, my TestRational class won't run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your sequence of numbers is, but I will go with the following assumption:

If your goal is the simply return the value of `(1/2 + 3/4 + 5/6 + ... + 97/98 + 99/100) ^ 2`. Then I would suggest the following:

```
//This method will return the value of (1/2 + 3/4 + 5/6 + ... + 97/98 + 99/100) ^ 2
public int calc(){
    double denominator = 2;
    double numerator = denominator - 1; //in your sequence, numerator is always 1 less than denominator
    double sum = 0;

    while(denominator <= 100){
         sum = sum + (numerator / denominator); //shorthand sum += (numerator / denominator);
         denominator = denominator + 2; //shorthand denominator += 2;
         numerator = denominator - 1;
    }

    return sum * sum; //this is equivalent to sum ^ 2
}
```

Comment: Just plain dividing those integers is useless though, especially since the denominator is always bigger than the numerator.

Comment: You're right Harold, I've edited the variables to be doubles.

Comment: The result too I guess? Then we get approximately the same results which is promising